# Quorum and Swarm Integration

Tags: quorum

After building from Quorum source, I can see Swarm as on the binaries. How can one get Swarm to work alongside Quorum?

Answer (score 0):

Quorum is first an Ethereum client.

It's based on Geth, the Go client implementation of Ethereum but adds some privacy features such as private transactions.

Quorum is then capable to use smart contracts as the main Ethereum protocol and so also use Swarm as decentralized storage. The use of Swarm is then the same as for the main Ethereum client.
See [What is Swarm and what is it used for?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/375/what-is-swarm-and-what-is-it-used-for) and http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html for more information about Swarm.

Comment: okay understood. Thanks. how then to get them working with each other?

Comment: @NathanAw what do you mean by "working with" ? Swarm is a decentralized storage. You can store whatever you like in it. Then you can retrieve the data from Swarm for using it in your dApp. But this is not tied to Quorum or even the client (Geth, Parity, whatever) as soon as you access Swarm with the Swarm client or a Swarm enabled browser or using a Swarm gateway or even Fuse mount it. 
Have a look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/388/405 or chapter 4 of https://dickolsson.com/tag/how-to-build-dapps/ or this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/37105/405

Comment: Also as for Geth, see enabling Swarm support https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/how-does-one-enable-and-use-swarm-demon-whisper-messaging-functionality-provid

Comment: I am getting this error: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54662/quorum-swarm-cant-find-swarm-account-no-key-for-given-address-or-file?noredirect=1#comment64866_54662 any idea and tips, please?