# Quorum Swarm: Can't find swarm account: no key for given address or file

Tags: quorum, swarm

While using Swarm in Quorum, I am getting the following error: Can't find swarm account: no key for given address or file

Any similar encounters?

Comment: Please do not spam.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same question. The one you indicated for duplicate is about running swarm It seems that he found out how to run swarm but encounter an address problem. I propose we reopen if you don't mind.

Comment: this is not a spam nor a robot but a genuine question. @niksmac . I am sincere.

Comment: Quorum is a third-party application, and support questions for getting it running properly would probably best be asked [directly on that application's issues list](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues).

Comment: i disagree -- quorum is ethereum based and shares a somewhat similar roadmap and therefore this is also a good avenue to share questions so others can benefit from the solutions easily.